Implement Cognito in ELSA
I'm trying to integrate AWS Cognito with my existing ELSA authentication system.
I attempted this but encountered issues. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or example on how to successfully implement Cognito with ELSA?
Also how to change the default username and password?
